# Release NSInteger type variable

Tags: ios

I am really confused with the code,my question is why I am getting value of the variables after releasing.

```
NSNumber *a=[[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:2];
NSNumber *b=[[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:3];
b=a;

[a release];
[b release];
NSLog(@"a=%@",a);
NSLog(@"b=%@",b);
```

OUTPUT: a=2
        b=2

when I am allocating the veriables retain count increments by 1,I have no other code where retain count increments.So my question is after release message retain count will be 0 and the objects will be deallocated and I should not get the value.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Hi all I found an answer but the logic behind it is not clear to me,If I put "I" after the integer number it gives the desired output.Will you please help.

```
NSNumber *a=[[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:2I];
NSNumber *b=[[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:3I];
b=a;

[a release];
[b release];

NSLog(@"a=%@",a);
NSLog(@"b=%@",b);
```

OUTPUT: a=0
        b=0

Comment: Because you didn't use the search. (This was ***just*** asked yesterday.) Also, I see no `NSInteger`s here. (Not that you could release an `NSInteger`, but stil...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [confused about ios release & dealloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080139/confused-about-ios-release-dealloc)

Comment: you may find duplicate as I am still confused.

Comment: after release add a=nil and b=nil because relase is only for decrease the reference counter not remove the objects from memory

Comment: Try searching for this term in the stack overflow search -> "[ios] access variable after release" and I guarantee you will find a general explanation.

Comment: @Parinita I just noticed the dupe yesterday was also asked by you. Please don't ask duplicates of the same question.

Comment: @H2CO3 what about the next part?will you please explain?and duplicate is just because till date I received no proper solution

Comment: @Parinita The thing is that you have undefined behavior all over the place, and as such, it's completely pointless to try to explain what your program does. It's free to do anything, so any output is correct and expected (until you don't fix your code).

Comment: I have these 4 lines only,what I need to fix?@H2CO3

Comment: @Parinita You don't release the objects before printing them, only at the end.

Answer (score 1):

When you send a release message on an object, the object is actually not being removed from the memory. The release message simply decrements the reference count by one only. If the reference count is zero the object is marked as free. Then the system remove it from the memory. Until this deallocation happens you can access your object. Even if you release the object your object pointer still points to the object unless you are assigning nil to the pointer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,here when I am allocating the veriables retain count increments by 1,I have no other code where retain count increments.So my question is after release message retain count will be 0 and the objects will be deallocated and I should not get the value.

Comment: @Pradeep I think your answer is incorrect. Here the objects are getting deallocated. And in fact, even deallocation doesn't mean "removal from memory".